# SVG animation via SMIL. Repeat animation bug in Safari

Tags: html, animation, svg, smil

I have a relatively simple path animated via SMIL. Everything works as expected in Chrome and Firefox. IE/Edge support is irrelevant.

Safari, however, behaves strangely and is easy to recreate. Unfortunately, it is crucial that Safari works.

```
<nav>
  <button id="button1" onClick="document.getElementById('animate1').beginElement()">1</button>
  <button id="button2" onClick="document.getElementById('animate2').beginElement()">2</button>
  <button id="button3" onClick="document.getElementById('animate3').beginElement()">3</button>
  <button id="button4" onClick="document.getElementById('animate4').beginElement()">4</button>
  <button id="button5" onClick="document.getElementById('animate5').beginElement()">5</button>
</nav>

<svg
  version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  x="0px"
  y="0px"
  width="100%"
  height="100%"
  viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"
  style="enable-background:new 0 0 1000 1000;"
  xml:space="preserve"
  preserveAspectRatio="none">

  <path d="M0,0 830,0 1000,300 1000,1000 500,1000 80,1000z">

    <animate id="animate1" attributeName="d" begin="indefinite" dur=".3s" fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" to="M0,0 830,0 1000,300 1000,1000 500,1000 80,1000z" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.4, 0, 0.2, 1" />
    <animate id="animate2" attributeName="d" begin="indefinite" dur=".3s" fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" to="M150,0 750,0 1000,150 1000,1000 500,1000 0,1000z" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.4, 0, 0.2, 1" />
    <animate id="animate3" attributeName="d" begin="indefinite" dur=".3s" fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" to="M50,0 750,0 1000,150 1000,1000 500,1000 0,1000z" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.4, 0, 0.2, 1" />
    <animate id="animate4" attributeName="d" begin="indefinite" dur=".3s" fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" to="M250,0 750,0 1000,450 1000,1000 500,1000 0,1000z" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.4, 0, 0.2, 1" />
    <animate id="animate5" attributeName="d" begin="indefinite" dur=".3s" fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" to="M0,0 930,0 1000,600 1000,1000 500,1000 80,1000z" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.4, 0, 0.2, 1" />

  </path>
</svg>
```

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vwWKYN

Upon click of *any* button, the path animates. Additional button clicks will properly animate the svg until the first button selected is clicked a second time.

E.g. Click on 4. 1,2,3,5 will work until you click 4 again. Once you click 4 a second time, the animation stops and you must select 1,2,3,5 in any order to 'unlock' the animation. Clicking any button other than the 4, they will continue to animate.

I've spent several hours on this and have attempted adding 'from' in addition to 'to', changed paths,  order, keySplines, keyTimes. I've also created a js function with the same result.

Note: I am trying to avoid the use of a third party library. I realize SMIL isn't as good as GSAP or Snap.js but this is all I need to animate and it mostly works.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you can report [webkit bugs here](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, reported. Keeping this up in case anyone has any clever ideas.

Comment: A bit late, but for anyone searching, Safari has a bug and requires resetting via `svg.pauseAnimations(); svg.setCurrentTime(0); svg.unpauseAnimations();` before repeat animations with `beginElement`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234572/strange-safari-behavior-with-multiple-svg-animates)