# Strange Safari behavior with multiple SVG <animate>'s

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, safari

I am attempting to animate an SVG play-stop button with multiple `<animate>` tags on a polygon, such that running `beginElement()` on each `<animate>` would cause the shape to morph its points. This works great in Chrome and Firefox, but, when testing in Safari, I only seem to be able to activate one `<animate>` tag.

The what I currently have is as follows:

```js
playState = true;

function toggle() {
  playState = !playState;
  document.querySelector("#to" + (playState ? "Play" : "Stop")).beginElement();
  console.log("Changed state to " + (playState ? "play" : "stop") + ".")
}

document.querySelector("#toggle").addEventListener("click", toggle);

toggle();
```

```css
#toggle circle {
  fill: #808080;
}

#toggle polygon {
  fill: #DCDCDC;
}
```

```html
<svg id="toggle" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
        <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"/>

<polygon points="150,150 150,150 150,150 150,150">
    <animate fill="freeze" id="toStop" attributeName="points" dur="500ms" to="100,100 100,200 200,200 200,100" begin="indefinite"     calcMode      = "spline"
    keySplines    = "0 0.75 0.25 1"
    keyTimes      = "0;1"/>
     <animate fill="freeze" id="toPlay" attributeName="points" dur="500ms" to="120,100 120,200 206.6025403784,150 206.6025403784,150" begin="indefinite"     calcMode      = "spline"
    keySplines    = "0 0.75 0.25 1"
    keyTimes      = "0;1"/>
    </polygon>

</svg>
```

Testing in Safari, I can correctly fire `#toPlay` initially, but, afterwards, running `beginElement()` on `#toPlay` flickers between the two states and activating `#toStop` does nothing. It is almost as though the `#toStop` animation is being delayed, and then is running rapidly when `#toPlay` is fired again.

Comment: You can file [webkit bugs here](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/)

Comment: Thanks, but a) how can I confirm that this is a WebKit bug, and b) is there any way to fix the problem in the meantime?

Comment: a) if Firefox and Chrome have common functionality and Safari does not then it's probably a webkit bug. b) You could write the animation in javascript without using SMIL.

Comment: I had originally chosen the soon-to-be-deprecated SMIL simply because it was so easy… is there any way to rewrite this in vanilla JS without much more effort?

Comment: A pure javascript answer would be much more work although there are libraries such as green that might make things easier. There are no plans by any browser to deprecate SMIL, in fact when Edge moves to be a Chrome clone, all browsers will support SMIL.

Comment: There are plans to deprecate SMIL, they were just suspended. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/blink-dev/5o0yiO440LM/YGEJBsjUAwAJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out on my own! However, I was forced to compromise slightly. [Jesus CMD explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37580637/9068081) that you need to reset the SVG animation on every other call to `beginElement()`. The downside of this solution is that the animation must be reset to the polygon points' *intial value,* so my hopes of having three possible polygon shapes (a single point, a square, and a triangle) must be narrowed down to only two states: play and stop.

The changed snippet is below.

```js
playState = true;
svg = document.querySelector("#toggle");

function toggle() {
  playState = !playState;
  if (playState) {

    svg.pauseAnimations();
    svg.setCurrentTime(0);
    svg.unpauseAnimations();
    document.querySelector("#toPlay").beginElement();
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#toStop").beginElement();
  }
  //document.querySelector("#to" + (playState ? "Play" : "Stop")).beginElement();
  console.log("Changed to " + (playState ? "Play" : "Stop"))
}

svg.addEventListener("click", toggle);
toggle();
```

```css
#toggle circle {
  fill: #808080;
}

#toggle polygon {
  fill: #DCDCDC;
}
```

```html
<svg id="toggle" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
        <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100"/>

<polygon points="100,100 100,200 200,200 200,100">
    <animate fill="freeze" id="toStop" attributeName="points" dur="500ms" to="100,100 100,200 200,200 200,100" begin="indefinite"     calcMode      = "spline"
    keySplines    = "0 0.75 0.25 1"
    keyTimes      = "0;1"/>
     <animate fill="freeze" id="toPlay" attributeName="points" dur="500ms" to="120,100 120,200 206.6025403784,150 206.6025403784,150" begin="indefinite"     calcMode      = "spline"
    keySplines    = "0 0.75 0.25 1"
    keyTimes      = "0;1"/>
    </polygon>

</svg>
```